# could not find SessionFactory in ehcace replication

Tags: hibernate, jpa, ehcache

I am trying to replicate my hibernate Entities in ehcache. 
This are my Entities:

Entity1: It has two composite primary key which is defined in `TableUserColumnViewID`

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "TMS_TAB_USER_COL_VIEW")
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_ONLY)
public class TableUserColumnViewEntity extends ZodiacWebEntity 
implements
Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private TableUserColumnViewId id;
    private Character visibleF;
    private Character colsFrozenF;
    private boolean isFilter;
    private Boolean sortOrderN;
    private String sortDirC;

    @EmbeddedId
    @AttributeOverrides({
        @AttributeOverride(name = "colId", column = @Column(name = 
            "COL_ID", nullable = false, precision = 22, scale = 0)),
        @AttributeOverride(name = "tabUserId", column = @Column(name = 
            "TAB_USER_ID", nullable = false, precision = 22, scale = 0))
    })
    public TableUserColumnViewId getId() {
        return this.id;
    }
}
```

Entity2:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "TMS_TAB_COL_ATTR")
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_ONLY)
public class TableColumnAttributeEntity extends ZodiacWebEntity 
implements
Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private Long colId;
    private String tabNm;
    private String colNm;
    private Byte pkColOdrN;
    private byte colOdrN;
    private Byte colDisOdrN;
    private String colDisNm;
    private String editActC;
    private String valRangeX;
    private Character nullableF;
    private String msgCode;
    private Byte colDisLenN;
    private String dispDateTime;
    private String sqlCheckX;
    private String autoGenerateSequenceAn;
}
```

Embeddable class:

```
public class TableUserColumnViewId implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private Long colId;
    private Long tabUserId;
}
```

This is my ehcache configuration to cache this both entities:

```
<cache name="com.zodiacweb.tblmtn.entity.TableUserColumnViewEntity"
    maxElementsInMemory="500" eternal="false"         
    timeToIdleSeconds="0" timeToLiveSeconds="3600" >
    <cacheEventListenerFactory
        class="net.sf.ehcache.distribution.RMICacheReplicatorFactory"
        properties="replicateAsynchronously=false, replicatePuts=true,
                    replicatePutsViaCopy=true, replicateUpdates=true,
                    replicateUpdatesViaCopy=true, replicateRemovals=true" />

    <bootstrapCacheLoaderFactory 
        class="net.sf.ehcache.distribution.RMIBootstrapCacheLoaderFactory"
        properties="bootstrapAsynchronously=false,
        maximumChunkSizeBytes=5000000" />
</cache>

<cache name="com.zodiacweb.tblmtn.entity.TableColumnAttributeEntity"
    maxElementsInMemory="500" eternal="false"         
    timeToIdleSeconds="0" timeToLiveSeconds="3600" >
    <cacheEventListenerFactory
        class="net.sf.ehcache.distribution.RMICacheReplicatorFactory"
        properties="replicateAsynchronously=false, replicatePuts=true,
                    replicatePutsViaCopy=true, replicateUpdates=true,
                    replicateUpdatesViaCopy=true, replicateRemovals=true" />

    <bootstrapCacheLoaderFactory
        class="net.sf.ehcache.distribution.RMIBootstrapCacheLoaderFactory"
        properties="bootstrapAsynchronously=false, 
        maximumChunkSizeBytes=5000000" />
</cache>
```

Now when I try to perform join query to get records from database.
It is putting in cache and working properly.

But when start replication my ehcache on multicast it is throwing me below exceptions.

```
2015-04-21 15:32:38 [net.sf.ehcache.distribution.RMISynchronousCacheReplicator :151 replicatePutNotification] [ERROR] [http-bio-8080-exec-10] - Exception on replication of putNotification. RemoteException occurred in server thread; nested exception is: 
java.rmi.UnmarshalException: error unmarshalling arguments; nested exception is: 
java.io.InvalidObjectException: Could not find a SessionFactory [uuid=3d1c934b-d851-4696-bde2-3abdb80d4137,name=null]. Continuing...
```

java.io.InvalidObjectException: Could not find a SessionFactory [uuid=3d1c934b-d851-4696-bde2-3abdb80d4137,name=null]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.locateSessionFactoryOnDeserialization(SessionFactoryImpl.java:1781) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.8.Final.jar:4.3.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.readResolve(SessionFactoryImpl.java:1761) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.8.Final.jar:4.3.8.Final]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_75]

Comment: Is it possible you had statistics on for your cache region? In Windows I get this error if I have statistics="true" set in one of my <cache> tags in ehcache.xml